# Use variables in script declaration

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page and I need to insert a script at the end of the file.

two pieces of the script definition depend on the query string of the page; so I have two pieces of the definition that changes based on the query string value.

I'm not able to figure out how to manage these variable parts in the script definition.

here what I need to obtain, where the "lang" equal to "it" and "cookiePolicyId" equal to "111111" are the dynamic parts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _iub = _iub || [];
_iub.csConfiguration = {"invalidateConsentWithoutLog":true,"lang":"it","siteId":123123,"consentOnContinuedBrowsing":false,"perPurposeConsent":true,"floatingPreferencesButtonDisplay":"bottom-right","askConsentAtCookiePolicyUpdate":true,"cookiePolicyId": 111111, "banner":{ "rejectButtonDisplay":true,"closeButtonDisplay": true,"closeButtonRejects": true,"listPurposes":true,"explicitWithdrawal":true,"position":"top","acceptButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonColor":"#424242" },
            "callback": {
                onPreferenceExpressedOrNotNeeded: function(preference) {
                    dataLayer.push({
                        iubenda_ccpa_opted_out: _iub.cs.api.isCcpaOptedOut()
                    });
                    if (!preference) {
                        dataLayer.push({
                            event: "iubenda_preference_not_needed"
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (preference.consent === true) {
                            dataLayer.push({
                                event: "iubenda_consent_given"
                            });
                        } else if (preference.consent === false) {
                            dataLayer.push({
                                event: "iubenda_consent_rejected"
                            });
                        } else if (preference.purposes) {
                            for (var purposeId in preference.purposes) {
                                if (preference.purposes[purposeId]) {
                                    dataLayer.push({
                                        event: "iubenda_consent_given_purpose_" + purposeId
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }};
</script>
```

This is my code (not working); the iublang and cookiePolicyId values are right but it does not insert them in the script definition

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // query string: ?language=it
        var iublang = "it";
        iublang = getParameterByName('language'); 
        var cookiePolicyId = 111111; // italiano
        console.log(iublang);
        if(iublang == "it") {
            cookiePolicyId = 111111;
        } else if(iublang == "fr") {
            cookiePolicyId = 222222;
        } else if(iublang == "en") {
            cookiePolicyId = 333333;
        } else if(iublang == "es") {
            cookiePolicyId = 444444;
        } else if(iublang == "de") {
            cookiePolicyId = 555555;
        }

var _iub = _iub || [];
_iub.csConfiguration = {"invalidateConsentWithoutLog":true,"lang":"`${iublang}`","siteId":123123,"consentOnContinuedBrowsing":false,"perPurposeConsent":true,"floatingPreferencesButtonDisplay":"bottom-right","askConsentAtCookiePolicyUpdate":true,"cookiePolicyId": `${cookiePolicyId}`, "banner":{ "rejectButtonDisplay":true,"closeButtonDisplay": true,"closeButtonRejects": true,"listPurposes":true,"explicitWithdrawal":true,"position":"top","acceptButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonColor":"#424242" },
            "callback": {
                onPreferenceExpressedOrNotNeeded: function(preference) {
                    dataLayer.push({
                        iubenda_ccpa_opted_out: _iub.cs.api.isCcpaOptedOut()
                    });
                    if (!preference) {
                        dataLayer.push({
                            event: "iubenda_preference_not_needed"
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (preference.consent === true) {
                            dataLayer.push({
                                event: "iubenda_consent_given"
                            });
                        } else if (preference.consent === false) {
                            dataLayer.push({
                                event: "iubenda_consent_rejected"
                            });
                        } else if (preference.purposes) {
                            for (var purposeId in preference.purposes) {
                                if (preference.purposes[purposeId]) {
                                    dataLayer.push({
                                        event: "iubenda_consent_given_purpose_" + purposeId
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*insert them in the script definition*"? Do you expect the insertion to happen at the server, generating a script with a literal value?

Comment: it is a simple html page so I can't manage the "insertion" of the value by the server (like with php). I need it to happen on the html page